# Discord low performance

Tags: ubuntu, performance, discord, nouveau

I have an fx-8320E and RX 480 4GB, I have 16GB of RAM, 13GB free, I'm curretnly running Ubuntu 18.10 and my Discord is slow.

I've installed latest nouveau and AMDGPU-PRO drivers, but neither make Discord work better, furthermore, all games I've played on it so far work flawlessly. I tried enabling and disabling HW Acceleration in Discord settings, but there was no visible change to the performance.

Discord is laggy while scrolling through any sidebar and when typing, letters start appearing after a second, so it's really hard to use. The performance is slightly better in non-maximised window form, but it's still quite laggy.

Any ideas, maybe someone has had a similar experience.

Kind regards, MG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running `snap remove discord` and installing their PTB(Public Test Build), it works flawlessly now!

Comment: This worked for me also.  Any idea what's different?

Comment: I have no idea, but maybe they've done an oopsie with their updates and could've disabled or published a non-working version of HWAccel...